Why can't I properly divide this array of strings into smaller groups?
I'm a beginner in C programming whose still pretty confused by arrays. I'm trying to create a program where an array of 42 names (alphabetically arranged) is divided into 7 groups each with 5 members. The tricky part is its ordering. The first group consists of the first member, the last member, the second member, the second to the last member, and the third member. Basically it alternates between the first and the last.
This is what I've tried so far:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char students[42][50] = {"Alde", "Amio", "Ande", "Ayuson", "Bacabac", "Bisares", "Caparuzo", "Castro", "Dela Cruz", "Devera", "Frias", "Gailo", "Galvez", "Gamboa", "Geronimo", "Gutierrez", "Hernandez", "Landoy", "Lasay", "Lopez", "Luna", "Manalang", "Maranguis", "Matro", "Mercado", "Millonte", "Morshed", "Naz", "Neri", "Ogbac", "Oredina", "Pardillo", "Pedido", "Perez", "Piedad", "Rodriguez", "Santos", "Sañosa", "Takeuchi", "Uy", "Ventura", "Villavicencio"};
    int numberOfStudents = sizeof(students) / sizeof(students[0]);
    int j = numberOfStudents - 1;
    int numberOfGroups = 7;
    int groupSize = 5;
    char group[7][5][50] = {};
    int m = 0;

    for (int l = 0; l < numberOfGroups; l++) {
        int x = 0;  // Reset x for each group
        for (int i = 0; i < groupSize; i++) {
            if (j >= 0) {
                strcpy(group[l][x], students[m]);  // Use m for the first student
                x++;
                strcpy(group[l][x], students[j]);  // Use j for the second student
                x++;
                j--;
                m++;
            }
        }
    }

    // Print the groups
    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfGroups; y++) {
        printf("Group %d:\n", y + 1);
        for (int k = 0; k < groupSize; k++) {
            printf("\t%s\n", group[y][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

The first groups is correct, but I don't understand at all why in the other groups there are names that are skipped and names that are repeated.

If you divide 42 into 7 groups of 5, what should happen to the other 7?


In the loop for (int i = 0; i < groupSize; i++) you increase the value of x twice. That means you will increase its value groupSize * 2 times, and it will become out of bounds after a couple of iterations.

— An answer originally posted by Some programmer dude in a comment

@SimonGoater Going out of bounds leads to undefined behavior. And once you have UB all discussion about behavior go out the window.

You loop groupSize times:
for (int i = 0; i < groupSize; i++)

... and inside the loop you do this:
   strcpy(group[l][x], students[m]);
   x++;
   strcpy(group[l][x], students[m]);
   x++;

This means x will loop from 0 to groupSize * 2 and group[l][x] will access the array out of bounds as soon as x reaches the value of groupSize. This has undefined behavior and can cause crashes or worse.
A simpler approach would be to instead use a loop over all the students and pick from the front and from the back every other time:
#define MIN(l, r) ((l) < (r) ? (l) : (r))

// ...

// calculate end of the loop:
const size_t studentsToGroup = MIN(numberOfGroups * groupSize, numberOfStudents);

for (size_t stud = 0; stud < studentsToGroup; ++stud) {
    // pick from the back or from the front?
    size_t idx = (stud % 2) ? numberOfStudents - stud / 2 - 1 : stud / 2;

    // copy to the correct group:
    strcpy(group[stud / groupSize][stud % groupSize], students[idx]);
}

Demo

Problem:
I noticed that your inner loop with i is crossing the boundary of x. Which cause the group to overflow in stack memory regions.
You are increasing 2 times x for every iteration of i for at the end of this loop if you try to print x which is 10. Because 2 * i => 2 * 5 = 10.
Corrected code:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    const char students[42][50] = {"Alde", "Amio", "Ande", "Ayuson", "Bacabac", "Bisares", "Caparuzo", "Castro", "Dela Cruz", "Devera", "Frias", "Gailo", "Galvez", "Gamboa", "Geronimo", "Gutierrez", "Hernandez", "Landoy", "Lasay", "Lopez", "Luna", "Manalang", "Maranguis", "Matro", "Mercado", "Millonte", "Morshed", "Naz", "Neri", "Ogbac", "Oredina", "Pardillo", "Pedido", "Perez", "Piedad", "Rodriguez", "Santos", "Sañosa", "Takeuchi", "Uy", "Ventura", "Villavicencio"};
    int numberOfStudents = sizeof(students) / sizeof(students[0]);
    int j = numberOfStudents - 1;
    int numberOfGroups = 7;
    int groupSize = 5;
    char group[7][5][50] = {};
    int m = 0;

    for (int l = 0; l < numberOfGroups; l++) {
        int x = 0;  // Reset x for each group
        for (int i = 0; i < groupSize; i++) {
            if (j >= 0) {
                strcpy(group[l][x], students[m]);  // Use m for the first student
                x++;
                m++;
                if(x == groupSize) break;
                strcpy(group[l][x], students[j]);  // Use j for the second student
                x++;
                j--;
                
            }
        }
       
    }

    // Print the groups
    for (int y = 0; y < numberOfGroups; y++) {
        printf("Group %d:\n", y + 1);
        for (int k = 0; k < groupSize; k++) {
            printf("\t%s\n", group[y][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}



@Kyle i don't change all the code to work in efficient way but I just fixed the mistakes to work the way you expected

@Kyle  your students array contains 42 students .if you divided it into 5 members for each group 42 / 5 = 8 not 7.You don't need the last group?

First lets point out problem in your code:
The inner for loop will iterate for 5 times as the value of groupSize is 5. In every iteration, it will increase m by 1, decrease j by 1 and increase x by 1 twice. That means, after first iteration value of m will be 5, value of j will be 36 and of x will be 10.
It's clear that because of incrementing x twice in loop, your code end up accessing the group array beyond it's size. This is undefined behavior.
Moreover, in next iteration m starts with 5 and j starts with 36 which is also incorrect because the first group should contain members of students array index - 0, 41, 1, 40, 2 (in this sequence). Which means, after first iteration, value of m should be 3 and value of j should be 39.
If the inner for loop is running for groupSize iterations, then you shouldn't call strcpy() twice in it's body. Otherwise, run loop for ((groupSize/2) + 1) iterations and do some hack in last iteration, of inner for loop, based on current group processing (whether it's odd or even) to set value of index j and m.
Instead, you can just have a loop which iterates for group array capacity or number of students times, whichever is less, and, in every iteration, copy appropriate student name to group array.
Here is the implementation:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define GRPS_NUM 7
#define GRP_SIZE 5
#define BUF_SIZE 50

int main(void) {

    const char students[][BUF_SIZE] = {
        "Alde", "Amio", "Ande", "Ayuson", "Bacabac", "Bisares", "Caparuzo",
        "Castro", "Dela Cruz", "Devera", "Frias", "Gailo", "Galvez", "Gamboa",
        "Geronimo", "Gutierrez", "Hernandez", "Landoy", "Lasay", "Lopez", "Luna",
        "Manalang", "Maranguis", "Matro", "Mercado", "Millonte", "Morshed", "Naz",
        "Neri", "Ogbac", "Oredina", "Pardillo", "Pedido", "Perez", "Piedad",
        "Rodriguez", "Santos", "Sañosa", "Takeuchi", "Uy", "Ventura", "Villavicencio"};
      
      
    size_t numberOfStudents = sizeof(students) / sizeof(students[0]);
    char group[GRPS_NUM][GRP_SIZE][BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    bool end = 0;
    int  count = 0;
    
    size_t itrs = numberOfStudents < (GRPS_NUM * GRP_SIZE) ? 
                  numberOfStudents : GRPS_NUM * GRP_SIZE;
    
    for (size_t x = 0; x < itrs; ++x) {
        int indx = end ? (numberOfStudents - 1) - count : count;
        strcpy(group[x / GRP_SIZE][x % GRP_SIZE], students[indx]);
        if (end) count++;
        end = !end;      // toggle between front and end
    }


    // Print the groups
    for (size_t x = 0; x < itrs; ++x) {
        if (!(x % GRP_SIZE)) {
            printf("Group %zu:\n", (x / GRP_SIZE) + 1);
        }
        printf("\t%s\n", group[x / GRP_SIZE][x % GRP_SIZE]);
    }    

    return 0;
}

Output:
Group 1:
    Alde
    Villavicencio
    Amio
    Ventura
    Ande
Group 2:
    Uy
    Ayuson
    Takeuchi
    Bacabac
    Sañosa
Group 3:
    Bisares
    Santos
    Caparuzo
    Rodriguez
    Castro
Group 4:
    Piedad
    Dela Cruz
    Perez
    Devera
    Pedido
Group 5:
    Frias
    Pardillo
    Gailo
    Oredina
    Galvez
Group 6:
    Ogbac
    Gamboa
    Neri
    Geronimo
    Naz
Group 7:
    Gutierrez
    Morshed
    Hernandez
    Millonte
    Landoy


This way makes so much more sense. Thanks!

You are handling it the harder way. The difficult part is that the second group should start with the third from the end because each group has an odd number of elements. So if you go that way, you should handle differently the even and odd groups.
IMHO, it should be simpler to take the elements from the original array and store them in their correct group and index, one starting from the beginning and one starting from the end. You end the loop when either pointers from the beginning and the end of the original array meet together (no element left in the array) or when all the groups are full. In pseudo code the algorithm could be:
initialize: beg = 0, end = numberOfStudents - 1, igroup = 0, index = 0
loop {
    // copy one from the beginning
    copy students[beg] into group[igroup][index]
    index += 1
    if (index == groupSize) {
        index = 0
        igroup += 1
        if (igroup == numberOfGroups) break  // last group is full
    }
    beg += 1
    if (beg == end) break                    // all elements have been copied
    // copy one from the end
    copy students[end] into group[igroup][index]
    index += 1
    if (index == groupSize) {
        index = 0
        igroup += 1
        if (igroup == numberOfGroups) break  // last group is full
    }
    end -= 1
    if (beg == end) break                    // all elements have been copied
}

